# Using for loop in Lua programming

Tags: lua

I have a string which delimited by `\n`, and I'm using `for` to do something with that. But I don't want the `for` loop to the end of the string, just want the for loop to any times like this code below but it doesn't work.

```lua
for w=1,10 in webdata:gmatch("(.-)\n") do 
    --something
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different `for` loops in Lua. You are mixing them together.

#### Numerical `for`:

```
for i=1,10 do -- or e.g. i=10,1,-1
   -- do something
end
```

#### Generic `for`:

```
for k,v in pairs(t) do -- or ipairs, or completely custom functions
   -- do something
end
```

For more information please refer to:

- [PIL - 4.3.4 – Numeric for](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html)
- [PIL - 4.3.5 – Generic for](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html)
- [Lua Reference Manual - 3.3.5 – For Statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

#### Your problem

To achieve your goal you could wrap `gmatch` with another iterator or... just go with the most straight-forward and simple solution: count the lines you have processed:

```
local n = 1
for l in webdata:gmatch("(.-)\n") do
   -- do something
   n = n + 1
   if n > 10 then
      break
   end
end
```

It's not the most elegant one, but it works.